# How to pass parameters to all of the inner workflow tasks inside a Map task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I am trying to use a Map task inside my State Machine. The design is simple - I have a lambda function that generates a list that the Map state uses. Each task inside the Map task should have access to the list's properties.

Right now I am observing that only the 1st task "ETL" get's each list element as an input but not the second task "WELL CALC".

[image]

My Step Machine fails with

```
{
  "error": "States.Runtime",
  "cause": "An error occurred while executing the state 'WELL CALC' (entered at the event id #15). The JSONPath '$.basinName' specified for the field 'basin.$' could not be found in the input '{}'"
}
```

The above error is true, the result of the ETL lambda task returns an empty object. Is there a way I can pass the "current item" of the Map iteration to all of the tasks as input?

This is my State Machine definition:

```
{
  "StartAt": "Generate Basin List",
  "States": {
    "Generate Basin List": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:451713003466:function:StepFunctionsSample-HelloLam-CheckStockPriceLambda-15TO7SRHAQYQV",
      "Next": "Process Basins"
    },
    "Process Basins": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemsPath": "$.BasinList",
      "End": true,
      "Iterator": {
        "StartAt": "ETL",
        "States": {
          "ETL": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:451713003466:function:StepFunctionsSample-HelloLambda0b4d-BuyStockLambda-1WW8B8JQSZ0SY",
            "Next": "WELL CALC"
          },
          "WELL CALC": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "End": true,
            "Parameters": {
              "basin.$":"$.basinName",
              "phases.$":"$.phases"
            },
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:451713003466:function:StepFunctionsSample-HelloLambda0b4-SellStockLambda-15I8EE3RWDMS5"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the "Generate Basin List" lambda:

```
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
    return {
        "BasinList": [
            {
                "basinName": "ARDMORE_AND_MARIETTA_BASINS",
                "phases": "1,4,5,8,9,10,13"
            }
        ]
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I can add `"ResultPath": null` field to the first state inside the Map - `ETL` which would result in the whole input state being passed as an output to the next state (source - https://states-language.net/spec.html#filters):

```
...
"ETL": {
    "Type": "Task",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us..."
    "Next": "WELL CALC",
    "ResultPath": null
},
...
```